# Is it possible to use JQuery.Load() to replace the entire document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

```
    $(document).load("somepage.aspx", function (responseText, textStatus, xhr) {

});
```

This is not working.
Is there any way to use the load function to replace the entire document including the head?

**EDIT: I don't want to refresh my page, I have to use AJAX.**

Comment: The normal built-in behavior of an HTML `<form>` is to run an HTTP request and replace the entire page with what's returned ...

Comment: To "replace the entire document including the head" is precisely, exactly the same as refreshing the page. I suspect that what you want to do is replace the content but preserve the window properties etc., right?  You should state that more clearly.

Comment: I'm using ajax to receive push notifications from my server, I want to avoid refresh my pages and use ajax in the background for that. Beatport.com have done something similar, so their audio player will still play even if you continue browsing.

Comment: @Adir an audio player wouldn't continue playing if you replaced the entire document, so you are misunderstanding what they do.

Comment: @Adir what **exactly** do you mean by the word "refresh" here?

Answer (score 7):

```
$.get("somepage.aspx", function (data) {
    document.open();
    document.write(data);
    document.close();
    $.cache = {};
}, "text");
```

Comment: @Adir nope, why would you think so.

Comment: @Adir yes, I tried it in chrome and firefox, and no refresh happened, I asked what makes you think a refresh happened?

Comment: Looking on the Firebug Net Tab

Comment: @Adir please show a screenshot or be more specific, you can easily see that there is no refresh by saving a variable before the call, and seeing if that variable has value in the callback. If the page had refreshed, that variable wouldn't exist because refreshing would have cleared all javascript on the page.

Comment: On Firefox I can clearly see the page becomes blank for a second, on Google Chrome it is working.

Comment: @Adir right, you can also `$("body").hide()` and then show it after 100 milliseconds, do you now think the page refreshed ? :)

Comment: The HTTP requests list on Firebug Net Tab clears = The browser refreshed the page.

Comment: That doesn't mean anything :'(

Comment: did you try running it on firefox?

Comment: @Adir yes, like I said, you can reliably see if refresh happened by setting a variable, and then trying to see if it exists. For example: `var a = "";
document.location.reload();
alert(a);` will cause a reference error because `a` doesn't exist after a refresh. You can however `document.write` and `a` will still exist because it didn't cause a refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Jquery Ajax query to grab some html from the server the remove everything from the document and replace it with the content.

Comment: I tried that but using innerHTML(or JQuery html function) strips out the scripts tags inside the loaded page.

Answer (score 0):

You can add iframe and load new page into it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $.get('my_page.html', function(e){
        $(document).empty().append(e);
    });
});
```

Try that. my_page.html gets loaded, then jQuery finds the document object, removes everything and appends it with the my_page.html content.

Comment: That gave me an a blank document, no idea why

Comment: You'll need to change the 'my_page.html' to the page you want to load.

Comment: Try change `$(document)` to `$('html')`

Answer (score 0):

You should redirect you page when page is completely loaded.

```
    $(window).load(function(){
       document.href.location = "your_page";
    });
```